# Cannot make a connection between R and Snowflake driver

Tags: sql, r, odbc, dbi, snowflake-connector

Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SnowflakeDSIIDriver' : file not found

I am having issues with Snowflake ODBC driver that was set up on my M1 chip Macbook Air. It is currently being stored in '/opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/universal/libSnowflake.dylib'. Everytime I attempt to create a connection using dbConnect, the error above pops up. I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling the driver multiple times, but nothing seems to work. Any tips?

Comment: Hi - have you followed all the steps in the documentation here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-mac.html

Comment: Yes, I have also uninstalled and reinstalled everything, in case it was order specific.

Comment: I don't think Snowflake have released an M1 compiled driver for Snowflake yet. I've heard that this will be released at the end of March 2022.

Comment: The driver is available now - https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/odbc/macaarch64/index.html
If you are using rstudio, you might need to reinstall the `odbc` package after following snowflake's install instructions to make the rstudio connections pane display the databse data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

New driver that came in May/June was the solution to this problem. As mentioned in the comment above.

Link for macs with MX (M1, M2...) architecture:
https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/odbc/macaarch64/index.html